# Broadcast or Multicast Pattern (SQS and SNS)

Tags: amazon-web-services, design-patterns, amazon-sqs, amazon-sns

Following is a message design pattern :

[image]

Step 1- Application sends message to SNS Topic

Step 2- SNS publishes message to subscribed SQS queue .

As per following definitions :

Broadcast : Message is published to all end points.

Multicast : Message is published to selected endpoints.

Above diagram can be interpreted as 
Option 1 - Message is published to selected SQS queues which are subscribed to SNS topic , multicast pattern

OR

Option 2 - Message is published to all subscribed end points,broadcast pattern

how should this design pattern be interpreted ?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

In the absence of clarification, this is likely to be broadcast.

The publisher can't select the queues that will receive the messages -- it will go to all of them, by default.

Historically, SNS fanout to SQS was always broadcast.

However, recent enhancements of SNS provide a capability for the subscriptions of each queue to the SNS topic to be "filtered" -- in which case, the publisher still can't directly select the queues that will receive the message (they're not explicitly addressable), but SNS makes decisions on where to deliver the messages based on the subscription filters... which might fit the multicast label, depending on the circumstances.

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sns/latest/dg/message-filtering.html